# Confused with the Way of Arduino Processing String

Tags: c++, arduino

```
void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);    //Set serial baud rate 9600
    pinMode(13,OUTPUT);    //Set LED for output
}
String str;
void loop()
{
    if(Serial.available() > 0)
    {
        char ch = Serial.read();
        str += ch;
    }
    if (str == "Hi")
    {
        digitalWrite(13,HIGH);    //Turns on the LED if "Hi" is entered.
    }
    if (str == "Bye")
    {
        digitalWrite(13,LOW);     //Turns off the LED if "Bye" is entered.
    }
}
```

I have a problem.  I think I don't know exactly how Arduino works when it reads String.
This is my sketch.
As you can see, it was intended to turn on the LED if "Hi" is entered and turn off if "Bye" is entered.
This compiles fine but whenever I connect serial port, upload it and turn on the LED with the word "Hi", I can't turn off the LED with the word "Bye".
Also if I enter "Bye" first and then "Hi", LED does not turn on.

What is a problem with my code? How can I modify it?

Comment: I would read up on http://arduino.cc/en/Serial/Read. Also use writing to the serial as a debugging log. So write str to serial frequently and compare it's value with the expected value to figure out where your code is wrong.

Comment: Is it supposed to disable with `"HiBye"`??? Questions must demonstrate minimal understanding of problem being solved...

Comment: @LS_dev No, I mean if I have a 'hit' with a word "Hi" and later 'hit' with a word "Bye", "Bye" does not do anything with LED.  About "HiBye", LED turns on, but for "ByeHi" it doesn't

Comment: Look at your code! Where are you reseting string after hit? when you send `Bye` after a `Hi`, result will be `HiBye`...

Comment: @LS_dev Now I see. Then how can I clear out string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must clear `str` after command accepted (or rejected):

```
str=NULL;
```

or

```
str="";
```

or

```
str=new String();
```

All those will assign a empty (or null) string to `str`.

I recommend you start learning [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b).

Comment: Great! Thanks a million.  I was searching for this answer:)

Comment: Could you explain to me why you recommend me learning C++? I'm a freshman and have no idea what to study next. I'm studying C.

Comment: Ok, you're in right way! Learn C very well, then start on C++. `String` and `Serial` are objects (C++), but you should learn C first, as you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it looks to me like you should be clearing out your str var once you have a hit. Because it sounds like it works on the first string but never on the second.

Once you detect a Hi or a Bye, you set the output and clear str.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Could you tell me how can I empty string?